# R: How to filter with two conditions of One column?

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements, subset

For example, I have three columns -ID column, Visit column, Drug column. The Drug column has character values of A,B,C and D. The problem is that each ID has either only A or B or C or D OR combo of A and B.

```
ID  Visit Drug 
1   1       A
1   2       B
1   3       A
2   1       B
2   2       B
3   1       C
3   2       C
```

So If I want to filter ID that has ONLY drug B (it cannot have both A and B) how do I filter this? From above, I only want ID 2 but  NOT ID 1 because ID 1 has both A and B.

I tried this code but it gives me wrong result

```
df %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
filter(drug == "B" | drug != "A" & drug != "B" )
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

In this case you should give a condition for the whole `Drug` vector, as with `all` in the following:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(Drug == "B"))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   ID [1]
#      ID Visit Drug 
#   <int> <int> <fct>
# 1     2     1 B    
# 2     2     2 B
```

Comment: If I want to filter on both A and B then do I do the same thing?...filter(all(drug_code == "A" & drug_code == "B")) it gives me 0 observation

Comment: You mean as to get `ID` equal to 1, in your example? In any case, `all(drug_code == "A" & drug_code == "B")` would never return anything. Take `df$Drug[1:3]` and see what happens: `df$Drug[1:3] == "A" & df$Drug[1:3] == "B"` would look (in a vectorized manner) for its elements that are `"A"` and `"B"` at the same time, which is impossible. What you want in this case is `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(c("A", "B") %in% Drug))` meaning that both `"A"` and `"B"` exist somewhere in `Drug`.

Comment: I suggest to take `df$Drug` and to try out `any`, `all`, `==`, `!=`, `x %in% y`, `y %in% x` to get good intuition on what is happening.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped!! I'll explore those above :)

Comment: I maybe wrong but  I believe c("A", "B") inside the all(c("A", "B") %in% Drug will give id's with '"either" A or B which is a little different from filtering Id's with both A and B

Comment: It will keep those `ID` that contain `"A"` at least once and `"B"` at least once, giving only `ID == 1`. If zero occurrences is also fine, but the elements of `Drug` can be only `"A"` or `"B"`, then you should use `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(Drug %in% c("A", "B")))`, giving `ID` as 1 and 2. (Meaning that `%in%` is not symmetric.)

Comment: Glad to help. I guess the answer could be accepted now.